# Azure Devops pipeline Yaml 'Toggle Block Comment' not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

In the Azure DevOps pipeline YAML editor, these options do nothing. This menu is available if you right-click on the editor and choose 'command palette' or press F1.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right, it seems like nor the menu nor the shortcut is working. However, the following shortcuts are working fine in the online editor:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Comment Block

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Uncomment Block